# WinApi Base Services tutorial?

Tags: c, winapi, wmi, wmi-query

I need to make application which gathers basic data about system, like OS version, processor & memory type, data about installed programs...
Application will be written in c and will work on Win Server 2000 and 2003. So first thing on my mind was WinApi, but i can not find any tutorials for these things, every tutorial i found is about UserInterfaces and i do not need that.

So any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Couple of things are answered below, and i will use WMI with WinApi, but still i dont know how to get detailed properties from any .exe program on windows??

Comment: In short..i need something to get started. :))

Comment: What specific properties do you want to retrieve for executables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582%28VS.85%29.aspx) is likely what you need for some stuff.  Not a fun API.  The tool Hans refers to would be useful - even if you have to port the generated C# code back to C.

The following Win32 APIs are likely to help you:

OS Version: [GetVersionEx and OSVERSIONINFOEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724451%28VS.85%29.aspx)

CPU Info: [cpuid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xs6aek1h%28VS.80%29.aspx) (either write it in assembly, or call the compiler intrinsic)

Alternate CPU Info: Just look at the registry key in HKLM\Hardware\DESCRIPTION\System\CentralProcessor (1 subkey for each logical processor, each key is a cache of what cpuid returns + processor speed is listed as well).

Memory: [GlobalMemoryStatusEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366589%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks a lot..last night I took some time to research WMI and it realy is not fun api to use but there is a lot of examples that will help..:)) But there is one more problem i have..Nor with WMI or WinApi a could not find how to get properties about installed programs. Those properties that can be found when right clicking on some .exe file -> properties -> details. If i find this i am ready to go. :))

Comment: You can get all the binary details using these apis:   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468915%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: well thank you a lot..i am really new with these things so it meant a lot..:))

Answer (score 1):

This isn't covered by the Winapi, you need WMI (Windows Management Instrumentation).  To get started on the kind of queries you can run, experiment with the [WMI Code Creator](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=2cc30a64-ea15-4661-8da4-55bbc145c30e&displaylang=en) tool.  It can auto-generate the code you need.  Not in C, you'll find that quite an awkward language for WMI.

Comment: hmm, i need to create program similar to this, of course not code creator, similar in part where i can get all those data. Problem is that system on which app will be used have no .NET framework, or JVM. So i need to do it in C or C++.

Comment: C++ is not a problem: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394558%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You probably also want to know about the book [**Windows Internals**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963901.aspx), from the same folk who make a wide range of [cool utilities](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/default.aspx) for poking under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

For Processor Information call
[GetLogicalProcessorInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683194%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Be Aware that this is not supported on all machines. So its better to call the DLL dynamically. Otherwise your program wont run on such machines. This [example](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCIQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dalun.com%2Fblogs%2F05.01.2007.htm&rct=j&q=GetLogicalProcessorInformation&ei=fvGFTMqdM8LqOOLSvZ8O&usg=AFQjCNHLHe6Iepqlj94oJWiTYzkWqsjBgw&sig2=aPygoEarVNiVISG591vBmA&cad=rja) show how to do this